# Is pd.concat the correct function for combining these two dataframes in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, api, dataframe, spotipy

I'm trying to access Spotify's API via the Spotipy library. I'm using a loop to build a dataframe of tracks and audio features for those tracks for the last 50 songs I listened to.

I imagine there are probably way more efficient ways of doing this, but as of now I've got a loop that can add data to an existing dataframe named `pddf`.

I'm hoping to do this by going row by row and adding columns, because the data added will be dependent on the track uri in that row.

```
for index, row in pddf.iterrows():
    track = list(row['track.uri'])
    track = re.findall('(?<=track:).*$', row['track.uri'])
    features = sp.audio_features(tracks=track)
    audio_features = pd.DataFrame(features)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    date = '%d/%d/%d' % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
    audio_features['Date'] = date
    audio_features = audio_features[
        ['Date', 'acousticness', 'analysis_url', 'danceability', 'duration_ms', 'energy', 'id',
         'instrumentalness', 'key', 'liveness', 'loudness', 'mode', 'speechiness', 'tempo', 'time_signature',
         'track_href', 'type', 'uri', 'valence']]
    pddf = pd.concat([pddf, audio_features], axis=0)
```

I have a feeling either `pd.concat` is the problem or the inefficient way I'm going about it, but it returns this:

```
0   2020-03-19T02:31:16.952Z    https://open.spotify.com/album/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    album   spotify:album:7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    album   [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'id': '4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'name': 'Don Toliver', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}]    ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    https://open.spotify.com/album/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B  [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 64}]    Heaven Or Hell  3/13/20 day 12  album   spotify:album:7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'id': '4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'name': 'Don Toliver', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}]    ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    1   180674  FALSE   USAT21904066    https://open.spotify.com/track/47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi    47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi  FALSE   Can't Feel My Legs  67  https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/64421f93c1a50553650656789726942083f5c567?cid=a98a5116ec7149be9fbec4e5ff8afc18 6   track   spotify:track:47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi                                                                            
1   2020-03-19T02:28:17.087Z    https://open.spotify.com/album/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    album   spotify:album:7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    album   [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'id': '4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'name': 'Don Toliver', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}]    ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    https://open.spotify.com/album/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B  [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 64}]    Heaven Or Hell  3/13/20 day 12  album   spotify:album:7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'id': '4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'name': 'Don Toliver', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}]    ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    1   171210  TRUE    USAT22001224    https://open.spotify.com/track/79EVtighsMYkWahVb9MnF8   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/79EVtighsMYkWahVb9MnF8    79EVtighsMYkWahVb9MnF8  FALSE   Wasted  68  https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/2d75b6c8a2699b911fbcaff1d2625bb6df4d183b?cid=a98a5116ec7149be9fbec4e5ff8afc18 5   track   spotify:track:79EVtighsMYkWahVb9MnF8                                                                            
2   2020-03-19T02:25:25.899Z    https://open.spotify.com/album/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    album   spotify:album:7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    album   [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'id': '4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'name': 'Don Toliver', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}]    ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    https://open.spotify.com/album/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B  [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 64}]    Heaven Or Hell  3/13/20 day 12  album   spotify:album:7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'id': '4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'name': 'Don Toliver', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}]    ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    1   167915  TRUE    USAT22001223    https://open.spotify.com/track/527k23H0A4Q0UJN3vGs0Da   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/527k23H0A4Q0UJN3vGs0Da    527k23H0A4Q0UJN3vGs0Da  FALSE   After Party 71  https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/647283c4f566948abd74087459fe592b5fd39dac?cid=a98a5116ec7149be9fbec4e5ff8afc18 4   track   spotify:track:527k23H0A4Q0UJN3vGs0Da                                                                            
3   2020-03-19T02:18:06.030Z    https://open.spotify.com/album/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    album   spotify:album:7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    album   [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'id': '4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'name': 'Don Toliver', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}]    ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    https://open.spotify.com/album/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B  [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 64}]    Heaven Or Hell  3/13/20 day 12  album   spotify:album:7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'id': '4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'name': 'Don Toliver', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/3xWSt0mL474uQlh5Zm6NsW'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3xWSt0mL474uQlh5Zm6NsW', 'id': '3xWSt0mL474uQlh5Zm6NsW', 'name': 'Offset', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:3xWSt0mL474uQlh5Zm6NsW'}, {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/0VRj0yCOv2FXJNP47XQnx5'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0VRj0yCOv2FXJNP47XQnx5', 'id': '0VRj0yCOv2FXJNP47XQnx5', 'name': 'Quavo', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:0VRj0yCOv2FXJNP47XQnx5'}]   ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    1   157133  TRUE    USAT21907692    https://open.spotify.com/track/6SPgp2qK3fb4wPX1SldrNf   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6SPgp2qK3fb4wPX1SldrNf    6SPgp2qK3fb4wPX1SldrNf  FALSE   Had Enough (feat. Quavo & Offset)   64  https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/8ef4943beb019f23b02252aab0b36c313ff31415?cid=a98a5116ec7149be9fbec4e5ff8afc18 9   track   spotify:track:6SPgp2qK3fb4wPX1SldrNf                                                                            
4   2020-03-18T22:16:21.225Z    https://open.spotify.com/album/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    album   spotify:album:7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    album   [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'id': '4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'name': 'Don Toliver', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}]    ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    https://open.spotify.com/album/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B   https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B  [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851da7dc7bd8beaa9bc9ceb8297', 'width': 64}]    Heaven Or Hell  3/13/20 day 12  album   spotify:album:7z4GhRfLqfSkqrj5F3Yt2B    [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'id': '4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs', 'name': 'Don Toliver', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:4Gso3d4CscCijv0lmajZWs'}]    ['AD', 'AE', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'BE', 'BG', 'BH', 'BO', 'BR', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CR', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'GR', 'GT', 'HK', 'HN', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IS', 'IT', 'JO', 'JP', 'KW', 'LB', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MA', 'MC', 'MT', 'MX', 'MY', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PH', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'SA', 'SE', 'SG', 'SK', 'SV', 'TH', 'TN', 'TR', 'TW', 'US', 'UY', 'VN', 'ZA']    1   180674  FALSE   USAT21904066    https://open.spotify.com/track/47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi    47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi  FALSE   Can't Feel My Legs  67  https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/64421f93c1a50553650656789726942083f5c567?cid=a98a5116ec7149be9fbec4e5ff8afc18 6   track   spotify:track:47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi                                                                            
0                                                                                                                                           3/19/20 0.237   https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi    0.703   180675  0.655   47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi  0   11  0.199   -6.226  0   0.0782  140.047 4   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi    audio_features  spotify:track:47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi    0.414
0                                                                                                                                           3/19/20 0.0714  https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/79EVtighsMYkWahVb9MnF8    0.743   171210  0.753   79EVtighsMYkWahVb9MnF8  3.02E-06    1   0.088   -4.479  1   0.0424  157.047 4   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/79EVtighsMYkWahVb9MnF8    audio_features  spotify:track:79EVtighsMYkWahVb9MnF8    0.695
0                                                                                                                                           3/19/20 0.00981 https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/527k23H0A4Q0UJN3vGs0Da    0.629   167916  0.692   527k23H0A4Q0UJN3vGs0Da  0.328   5   0.603   -8.045  1   0.0376  162.948 4   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/527k23H0A4Q0UJN3vGs0Da    audio_features  spotify:track:527k23H0A4Q0UJN3vGs0Da    0.453
0                                                                                                                                           3/19/20 0.262   https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/6SPgp2qK3fb4wPX1SldrNf    0.748   157133  0.789   6SPgp2qK3fb4wPX1SldrNf  0   2   0.13    -4.579  1   0.103   147.957 4   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6SPgp2qK3fb4wPX1SldrNf    audio_features  spotify:track:6SPgp2qK3fb4wPX1SldrNf    0.671
0                                                                                                                                           3/19/20 0.237   https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi    0.703   180675  0.655   47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi  0   11  0.199   -6.226  0   0.0782  140.047 4   https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi    audio_features  spotify:track:47IXLhp3c6mu7NqvpuhuLi    0.414
```

with the added data beginning on a **new** row, at the end of the dataset instead of attaching to each row...

If anyone can point me to where I went wrong, I'm stumped D:

Comment: you need to create a list that contains the audio_features you are generating at each iteration and then concat with pddf along axis=0.

Comment: you may also prefer using `now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` than using `'%d/%d/%d' % (now.month, now.day, now.year)`. I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a warning, I'm writing this on the assumption that pddf['track.uri'] and audio_features['uri'] are common columns between the two dataframes. If I'm misunderstanding the structure of your data, you may need to adjust the specific names I'm using in the example.

Okay, so the first problem you may be coming across has less to do with pd.concat() and more to do with the way you're approaching this. If you can, try to generate a DataFrame of the audio features in one go rather than generating a DataFrame in each loop. First, get the list of all of the track uri's that you need to use. Then you can use the loop to make a list of lists (or, even better, a list of tuples). *Then*, you can turn that into a DataFrame.

For actually turning it into a DataFrame, it's generally better to join them on a common key like the track uri using merge. In this case:

```
pddf = pddf.merge(audio_features,left_on='track.uri',right_on='uri')
```